# Get-ChildItem not detecting the existing drives

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script below which should logically work but throws below error saying "A drive with the name 'E" does not exist." But in fact it exists. This error comes when I input the drive using a variable, but if I input the drive that is path manually like "E:" it will work ok. Do no know what I am doing wrong.

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'E' does not exist.
At line:24 char:10
+ $list =  Get-ChildItem -path $CDDriveLetterToText
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (E:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoundExcepti    
on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

My code is as below.

```
Function Image-Windows10 () {
$CDDrives = Get-WmiObject win32_volume | where {$_.DriveType -eq '5'} | Select-Object -Property name
$FlashDrives = get-wmiobject win32_diskdrive | where {$_.InterfaceType -eq 'SCSI'} | select-object -property index, size
[int]$NumberOfFlashDrives=$FlashDrives.Count
[int]$NumberOfCDDrives=$CDDrives.Count
$CDDriveLetterToText = Out-String -inputObject $CDDrives.Get($NumberOfCDDrives-1)
$CDDriveLetterToText = $CDDriveLetterToText.Replace("name","").Replace("----","").Replace("`n","").Replace(" ","")

$list =  Get-ChildItem -Path $CDDriveLetterToText


}

Image-Windows10
```

Comment: Strange.  So you can successfully change location to `E:` but you get this error when trying to use Get-ChildItem with it?  What happens if you run `Get-ChildItem -Path E:` directly from the prompt?  Does the drive show up when you do `Get-PSDrive`?

Comment: Yes it does. When I do get-psdrive, the "E" drive shows there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of selecting the name you might want to go for the property `DriveLetter`. the parameter `-ExpandProperty` will return an array of the specified value - thus no need to manipulate the string'

```
# get all drive letters from devices of type 'CDRom'
$driveArray = Get-WmiObject win32_volume | where {$_.DriveType -eq '5'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DriveLetter

# this array can then be iterated like
foreach($drive in $driveArray) {
    $list = Get-ChildItem -Path $drive
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much "Guenther Schmitz". I do not know why but This actually worked for me, that is the "-ExpandProperty". I changed the like this and it worked. "$CDDrives = Get-WmiObject win32_volume | where {$_.DriveType -eq '5'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name" and "Get-ChildItem -path $CDDrives.Get($NumberOfCDDrives-1)"